# Is there a conditional abort return technique for C# shorthand if notation

Tags: c#, return, abort

Is there a conditional abort return technique for C# shorthand if notation ?

like:

```
return (a==b) ? true : abort;
```

if condition not satisfies, return will be aborted.

Comment: Can you describe what should happen if `a != b` ? Ok what do you mean by `return will be aborted`? Throwing exception? Continuing method execution? `Environment.FailFast();` ?

Comment: You mean like throwing an exception?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit it is an option, not necessarily.

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't you just do `if (a==b) return true;` - surely that's short enough already?

Comment: Is this equivalent to what you'd like? `if (a == b) return true;` If so, no, there is no shorthand for that in C# (I find the above to be quite readable and concise).

Comment: Can you tell the context in which you are doing this, since for a method you would have to return something right ! Maybe your problem area is something different

Comment: @serefbilge: did you already received an answer to this question?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: I didn't exactly, sorry for unchecking your answer. I gave you +1. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @serefbilge: if you do, please post it here, really interested in what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: :) Nothing more than shortening my expression. Sometimes I don't like to use if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking this question, so there might be a reason why you don't want to do this:

```
if (a==b) return true;
```

Above is very readable, maintainable, etc.

Anyway you could use a delegate with a lambda and do something like this (although I **strongly discourage it**):

```
delegate bool Abort();

bool YourMethod() // not mine ;)
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    return (a == b) || new Abort(() => { 
        // put the rest of your 'abort' code here
        return false; // or throw an exception...
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var res = Test();
        }

        static bool Test()
        {
            var a = 5;
            var b = 6;

            return a.TrueOrAbort(b);


        }

    }

    public static class MyHelper
    {
        public static bool TrueOrAbort<T>(this T first, T second) where T : struct, IComparable  
        {
            if (first.Equals(second)) 
                return true;

            Environment.Exit(0);

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this abort really if a != b?

Comment: sure. you can paste the code in an empty console application and debug it.

Comment: It aborts fully; is there a way only aborts "return"; I mean that, code  continues after return if a!=b.

Comment: then see comment from Matthew Watson

Comment: or... instead of Environment.Exit, you can throw an exception. then it will fit your comment "@WouterHuysentruit it is an option, not necessarily."

Comment: Ok, I understood; it can not be. Thanks for answer.